# Do new vinyl floorings still contain asbestos?

Tags: asbestos, vinyl-flooring

My dad bought some vinyl flooring tiles from Home Depot and cut some of it. As far as I can tell, the US never banned asbestos in flooring. He said they were made in China.

I had one tested using PLM and it came back negative (non detected), but the report said PLM test might be inconclusive for flooring tiles due to the small size of fibers. Should I get a more comprehensive TEM test?
Thanks

Comment: Are you only concerned with asbestos, or also rockwool, fiberglass or other known or suspected carcinogens that work on the same mechanism? They are only shades of grey different...

Comment: they certainly aren't supposed to, but tough flooring is the least problematic residential use case anyway; flaky ceiling tiles is what you really don't want...

Comment: Cutting a few tiles is usually not much to be concerned about.  Grinding/sanding tiles day in day out for a long time is.  Asbestos is bad for people who work with it everyday for years and breath in a decent amount.  Wearing a mask is not a bad idea and should be done for a lot of jobs.

Comment: While it _is possible_ for a single exposure to do harm, it is _highly unlikely_. As @crip659 noted, it's those who worked with asbestos day-in-day-out for years with no protective gear that ended up with problems.

Comment: the safety data sheet that I got from Home Depot states no asbestos is in it. I tested it using PLM method and it came back negative. Is it safe to assume there is no asbestos in it?

Comment: It is impossible to *prove* a negative.  Lack of a positive is evidence to support the negative case, which is as good as you can get.

Comment: Can't you just post a picture and link to product?

Answer (score 1):

American manufacturers don’t use asbestos in vinyl products today, but other countries continue to use asbestos in vinyl products and there’s no regulation on importing them into the U.S. I'll highly suspect the product from China.

The following brands of vinyl flooring contained asbestos:

**Congoleum-Nairn**

- Flor-Ever Vinyl
- Fashionflor
- Cushioned Vinyl
- Gold Seal Vinyl Inlaids
- Gold Seal Vinyl Nairon Standard

**Armstrong World Industries**

- Excelon Vinyl Asbestos Tiles
- Solarian Vinyl Asbestos Tiles

**Kentile Floors**

- KenFlex Vinyl Floor Tiles

**Montgomery Ward**

- Style House Vinyl Asbestos Flooring

**Sears-Roebuck**

- Vinyl Asbestos Floor Tiles

**EverWear**

- Vinyl Asbestos Floor Tiles

**Goodyear**

- Vinyl Tile

Companies that manufactured asbestos vinyl products include:

American Biltrite

Amtico Floors

Armstrong World Industries

Congoleum Corporation

EverWear

GAF Corporation

Goodyear

Kentile Floors

Montgomery Ward

Sears-Roebuck

https://www.asbestos.com/products/vinyl-products/

Comment: the safety data sheet that I got from Home Depot states no asbestos is in it. I tested it using PLM method and it came back negative. Is it safe to assume there is no asbestos in it?

Comment: I am not an expert, but as far as I know, unless the tile is flaking that permits the asbestos freely hanging in the air **with considerable amount and elonged exposure**, it should be considered safe. You can check the EPA website for precautions on asbestos exposures.